# Why do I get "undefined reference" errors when linking against OpenSSL?

Tags: gcc, openssl

My compilation process throws around errors like

```
..undefined reference to `BN_cmp'
```

although I include `<openssl/bn.h>`

and run
`gcc -lssl -lcrypto test.c -o test`

can someone help? (openssl libssl1.0.0, libssl-dev are installed)

Answer (score 18):

The solution is as simple as adding the `-l` flags at the *end*:

```
gcc test.c -o test -lssl -lcrypto
```

The order matters because `ld` since Ubuntu 11.04 is invoked with the `-as-needed` switch by default, so that files/libraries which depend on other libraries must come before these other libraries, i.e. `test.c` needs `libcrypto`, so it must come before `-lcrypto`.

For more information, see [Toolchain Transition in Natty Narwhal](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ToolchainTransition#How_to_Fix_a_Problem).